# debian apache config

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, ssl, debian-squeeze

Update, ok so this is my new sites-available config file Apache will fail to start.

```
#
#Document root
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"
    <Directory "/var/www">
        allow from 192.168.11.0/24
        deny from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#
#Production simplyaccomplished.com
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin frank_wiebenga@hotmail.com
        ServerName www.simplyaccomplished.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/simplyaccomplished/htdocs/"
    <Directory "/var/www/simplyaccomplished/htdocs/">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/simplyaccomplished/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>
        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog /var/www/simplyaccomplished/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>

#
#Production ssl simplyaccomplished.com
#
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin frank_wiebenga@hotmail.com
        ServerName www.simplyaccomplished.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/simplyaccomplished/htdocs/"
    <Directory "/var/www/simplyaccomplished/htdocs/">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>

    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/server.csr
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/server.key

        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/simplyaccomplished/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>
        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog /var/www/simplyaccomplished/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>

#
#Production dining.simplyaccomplished.com
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin frank_wiebenga@hotmail.com
        ServerName www.dining.simplyaccomplished.com
        ServerAlias *.dining.simplyaccomplished.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/dining/htdocs/"
        <Directory "/var/www/dining/htdocs/">
                allow from all
                Options +Indexes
        </Directory>
        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/dining/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>
        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog /var/www/dining/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>

#
#Production ssl dining.simplyaccomplished.com
#
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin frank_wiebenga@hotmail.com
        ServerName www.dining.simplyaccomplished.com
        ServerAlias *.dining.simplyaccomplished.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/dining/htdocs/"
        <Directory "/var/www/dining/htdocs/">
                allow from all
                Options +Indexes
        </Directory>

    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/server.csr
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/server.key

        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/dining/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>
        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog /var/www/dining/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my ports.conf

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>

    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

apache2.conf

```
#
# Based upon the NCSA server configuration files originally by Rob McCool.
#
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ for detailed information about
# the directives.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# The configuration directives are grouped into three basic sections:
#  1. Directives that control the operation of the Apache server process as a
#     whole (the 'global environment').
#  2. Directives that define the parameters of the 'main' or 'default' server,
#     which responds to requests that aren't handled by a virtual host.
#     These directives also provide default values for the settings
#     of all virtual hosts.
#  3. Settings for virtual hosts, which allow Web requests to be sent to
#     different IP addresses or hostnames and have them handled by the
#     same Apache server process.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "/etc/apache2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "/etc/apache2/foo.log".
#

### Section 1: Global Environment
#
# The directives in this section affect the overall operation of Apache,
# such as the number of concurrent requests it can handle or where it
# can find its configuration files.
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 15

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
## 

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadLimit: ThreadsPerChild can be changed to this maximum value during a
#              graceful restart. ThreadLimit can only be changed by stopping
#              and starting Apache.
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#

#
# DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain


#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostNameLookups on

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include all the user configurations:
Include httpd.conf

# Include ports listing
Include ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

<Directory "/var/www/">
</Directory>

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/config.conf
```

this is the location of my keys

```
root@bad-apple:/etc/apache2/ssl# ls -l
total 16
-r-------- 1 root root 1066 Feb  9 22:47 server.crt
-r-------- 1 root root  761 Feb  9 22:43 server.csr
-r-------- 1 root root  887 Feb  9 22:49 server.key
-r-------- 1 root root  963 Feb  9 22:48 server.key.secure
```

Anybody notice anything stupid I've done?
update forgot /etc/apache2/ssl in vhosts file fixed now getting

```
[Thu Feb 09 23:03:49 2012] [error] Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All SSL virtual hosts need an explicit "SSLEngine on"

The debian [docs](http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/pkg-apache/trunk/apache2/NEWS?revision=1225&view=markup) give you:

> apache2 (2.2.13-2) unstable; urgency=high
>
> ```
> * The new support for TLS Server Name Indication added in 2.2.12 causes
>   Apache to be stricter about certain misconfigurations involving name
>   based SSL virtual hosts. This may result in Apache refusing to start
>   with the logged error message:
>
>       Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured
>       [Hint: SSLCertificateFile]
>
>   Up to 2.2.11, Apache accepted configurations where the necessary SSL
>   configuration statements were included in the first (default)
>   <Virtualhost *:443> block but not in subsequent <Virtualhost *:443>
>   blocks. Starting with 2.2.12, every VirtualHost block used with SSL must
>   contain the SSLEngine, SSLCertificateFile, and SSLCertificateKeyFile
>   directives (SSLCertificateKeyFile is optional in some cases).
>
>   When you encounter the above problem, the output of the command
>
>       egrep -ir '^[^#]*(sslcertificate|sslengine|virtualhost)' \
>           /etc/apache2/*conf* /etc/apache2/*enabled
>
>   may be useful to determine which VirtualHost sections need to be changed.
>
>   Also, formerly accidentially working constructs like
>
>       <VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
>
>   where one virtual host definition is used for both a non-ssl and a ssl
>   virtual host do not work anymore. You can achieve a similar effect with
>
>       <VirtualHost *:80>
>       Include /.../vhost.include
>       </VirtualHost>
>       <VirtualHost *:443>
>       SSLEngine on
>       SSLCertificateFile ...
>       Include /.../vhost.include
>       </VirtualHost>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

To start with, the first `VirtualHost` directive for an IP takes precedence, so it'll override the defaults in `apache2.conf`. As you've put `*` for the IP, this will become the default for every address Apache is listening on.

The achieve what you're after, change the `DocumentRoot` and the `Directory` directive to be `/var/www`, which will serve out `/var/www` and everything under it - such as the directories you want available. Then, create separate `VirtualHost` sections for each of your apps - such as phpmyadmin.

You'll probably end up with something like this:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www"
  ServerName server.example.com
  <Directory "/var/www">
    Allow from all
    Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/phpmyadmin"
  ServerName phpmyadmin.example.com
  <Directory "/var/www/phpmyadmin">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/simplyaccomplished"
  ServerName simplyaccomplished.example.com
  <Directory "/var/www/simplyaccomplished">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note this isn't a complete Apache config - it's just to give you an idea.